# How do these OpenSSL commands create a Bitcoin private/key from a ECDSA keypair

Tags: openssl

I found the following code online and apparently it works. But I don't understand the lines which extract the Bitcoin compatible private/public key from the created ECDSA keypair.

```
FILE_NAME=$1
PRIVATE_KEY=${FILE_NAME}_private.pem
PUBLIC_KEY=${FILE_NAME}_public.pem
BITCOIN_PRIVATE_KEY=bitcoin_${FILE_NAME}_private.key
BITCOIN_PUBLIC_KEY=bitcoin_${FILE_NAME}_public.key

echo "Generating private key"
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -rand /dev/urandom -out $PRIVATE_KEY

echo "Generating public key"
openssl ec -in $PRIVATE_KEY -pubout -out $PUBLIC_KEY

echo "Generating BitCoin private key"
openssl ec -in $PRIVATE_KEY -outform DER|tail -c +8|head -c 32|xxd -p -c 32 > $BITCOIN_PRIVATE_KEY

echo "Generating BitCoin public key"
openssl ec -in $PRIVATE_KEY -pubout -outform DER|tail -c 65|xxd -p -c 65 > $BITCOIN_PUBLIC_KEY

echo "Files created!"
```

If someone could explain, that would be nice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bitcoin uses ECDSA so ECDSA keypairs are Bitcoin keypairs as well.

```
echo "Generating private key"
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -rand /dev/urandom -out $PRIVATE_KEY
```

This generates the private key in the pem format that openssl uses.

```
echo "Generating public key"
openssl ec -in $PRIVATE_KEY -pubout -out $PUBLIC_KEY
```

This generates the public key from the provided private key (which we just generated) and writes it to a file in the pem format.

```
echo "Generating BitCoin private key"
openssl ec -in $PRIVATE_KEY -outform DER|tail -c +8|head -c 32|xxd -p -c 32 > $BITCOIN_PRIVATE_KEY
```

This takes the private key in the pem format, converts it to the DER format, and extracts from that format the 32 bytes for the private key and writes those as a hex string to a file.

```
echo "Generating BitCoin public key"
openssl ec -in $PRIVATE_KEY -pubout -outform DER|tail -c 65|xxd -p -c 65 > $BITCOIN_PUBLIC_KEY
```

This takes the public key in the pem format, converts it to the DER format, and extracts from that format the 65 bytes for the public key and writes those as a hex string to a file.

Comment: Ok, so the "magic" I was missing is basically a format conversion.Thanks!

Comment: @Adrew `echo "Generating BitCoin public key"
openssl ec -in $PRIVATE_KEY -pubout -outform DER|tail -c 65|xxd -p -c 65 > $BITCOIN_PUBLIC_KEY` this takes private key not public key in pem version. Why I have to create $PUBLIC_KEY ?

Comment: You need the public key in pem form so that you can do public key operations with openssl. However, depending on what you are doing, it may not be necessary. I do not know what the original author's intent for this code was; my answer is only explaining what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Generation of both PrivKey and PubKey:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -text -noout -outform DER | xxd -p -c 1000 | sed 's/41534e31204f49443a20736563703235366b310a30740201010420/PrivKey: /' | sed 's/a00706052b8104000aa144034200/\'$'\nPubKey: /'
```

Gives following result:

```
PrivKey: 1f7ca3635605bc57b579b5fdf73e3ac84aa91a9c8eddc57aa0e3452d1a429ff8
PubKey: 0403af2a877e578086b277c6aa0622ed1bd0754cac48acdfff6591d235fa517d739ded3fd6b7e6394a4023623d67a35c836f853213d9709033f310996230469917
```

Or just:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -text -noout -outform DER | xxd -p -c 1000 | sed 's/41534e31204f49443a20736563703235366b310a30740201010420//' | sed 's/a00706052b8104000aa144034200/\'$'\n/'
```

Gives 2 following lines:

```
5be716d6bb3661a21cae21599bd94943508ba6566809705d2a1d6800741ac4e0
0424142e22f2fb297a804dda51b5a635ba871fba5d09b6133ac23da76433ccb97f727261262c40265c22040e96c275c5e682c698bc346d9e712222170d262647d1
```

To get Public Key from Private Key (replace `***` with private key):

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2n/bin/openssl ec -inform DER -text -noout -in <(cat <(echo -n "302e0201010420") <(echo -n "***") <(echo -n "a00706052b8104000a") | xxd -r -p) 2>/dev/null | tail -6 | head -5 | sed 's/[ :]//g' | tr -d '\n' && echo
```

Full investigation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213805/440168

Comment: I was struggling with this using the current openssl version I have, now I know why you used 1.0.2n https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/395

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using /dev/random instead of /dev/urandom
And, if you do it in VirtualBox you should share your host's /dev/random since the level of entropy in guest OS is low.

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -text -noout -outform DER | xxd -p -c 1000 | sed 's/41534e31204f49443a20736563703235366b310a30740201010420//' | sed 's/a00706052b8104000aa144034200/\'$'\n/'
```

for the above code... you're not creating bitcoin address but etheruem address