# How can you generate a bitcoin Public Key from an existing Private Key using openssl?

Tags: private-key, public-key, openssl

I know that you can generate a new key pair with a command like.

`openssl  ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1`

And the resulting output will contain a **new** private key with the encoded public key.

Is it possible for openssl to generate the public key straight from an existing private key only?

Just to be clear I mean Bitcoin Public Key and not Public Address

Comment: Check this out, it might help you [How do these OpenSSL commands create a Bitcoin private/key from a ECDSA keypair](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59644/how-do-these-openssl-commands-create-a-bitcoin-private-key-from-a-ecdsa-keypair)

Comment: @AllanRomanato Thanks but still doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, openssl shows a public key corresponding to a private key that is input, e.g.

```
$ openssl ec -in priv_key.openssl -text -conv_form compressed
```